# Set the SendTimeout on a WCF client callback binding?

Tags: c#, wcf, callback, nettcpbinding, duplex

I have a DuplexClientBase proxy with NetTcpBinding.

I set the SendTimeout on the DuplexClientBase at instantiation:

```
public class MyProxy : DuplexClientBase<IService>
{
    public MyProxy(IClient callback, Uri uri)
         : base(callback, new NetTcpBinding() { SendTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2.0)}, new EndpointAddress(uri))
        { ... }
```

The SendTimeout works as expected (client -> server) and the callback mechanism works as expected (server -> client), but the callback SendTimeout is not 2 seconds.

Is it possible to specify the SendTimeout for the callback proxy?

Answer (score 0):

A-ha!

After quite a bit of trial and error, I've found that the SendTimeout on the ServiceHost's NetTcpBinding is what controls the SendTimeout on duplex callbacks.